# How to trigger build using choice parameters in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, testng

I have a job which has multiple choice parameters which includes some testng.xmls of my project. I want to build those xmls in a specific order using choice parameters. Will there be a way to achieve my requirement using Jenkins without Build the xmls one by one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Choice Parameters, you can use [Active Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) to select the multiple xmls of your choice.

Example Jenkins Job Configuration:

[image]

[image]

Simple pipeline script:

```yaml
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Checkout SCM ') {
         steps {
             echo "${params.TestSuite}"
            
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: how will this work if i want to run the build periodically?